# Rails Paperclip updating model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have some problem with paperclip and active_admin gem. My model have attachment

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_attached_file :photo
    ///rest of code with style etc.

    def approve!
      self.update_attributes(:active => true, :abc=>true,:def=>true)
    end

end
```

When I do update from active_admin for this model, for example

```
a.approve!
```

Paperclip every time save new attachment for this model. I do somethings wrong or there is some option to disable this behavior?

When I have to approve 50 element it takes some times and server load...

Comment: no, this is example but I update more then one attribute

Comment: ok problem solved. I had before_save filter.

Comment: please, delete this question since there is no problem